# JSP Servlet URL patterns

Tags: java, jsp, web, servlets

I've created a Java web app (EE 8) that runs on the tomcat 10 server but doesn't work with URL(href link) in an index.JSP page; I haven't changed anything in the generated application. but throws 404 code in the "http://localhost:8080/hello-servlet" url. how to map URL with @webSevlet annotations.

```
 @WebServlet(name = "helloServlet", value = "/hello-servlet")
 public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
private String message;

public void init() {
    message = "Hello World!";
}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException 
   {
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    // Hello
    System.out.println("Get Requests");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html><body>");
    out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
    out.println("</body></html>");
   }

public void destroy() {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Including the project name might solve this. The structure of your URL should look like this: `http://localhost:8080/myProjectName/hello-servlet`. This is caused by tomcat, because it can host multible applications on one server and you probably did not upload it as default application.

---

You can find your project name in the `web.xml`:

`<display-name>myProjectName</display-name>`

---

Loads with status 200:
[image]

---

If any file of yours is working you can use this code to list all active servlets:

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Map"%>
<%
String jspUrl = request.getRequestURL().toString(); //the url of the current file
String[] parts = jspUrl.split("/");
String parentUrl = jspUrl.replace(parts[parts.length - 1], ""); //removes the file name
out.print(jspUrl + "<br>->" + parentUrl + "<br>List of all servlets: <br>");
Map<String, ? extends ServletRegistration> servletRegistrations = request.getServletContext().getServletRegistrations();
for (String servlet : servletRegistrations.keySet()) { //Loops trough every registered servlet
    ServletRegistration registration = servletRegistrations.get(servlet);
    String servletValue = new ArrayList<String>(registration.getMappings()).get(0); //get the first mapping
    String url = parentUrl + servletValue.replaceFirst("/", "");
    out.print("- " + servlet + ": <a href=\"" + url + "\">" + servletValue + "</a><br>");
}
%><br>
```

The output looks something like this and includes the URLs (clickable) to the listet sites:

```
http://localhost:8080/myProject/index.jsp
->http://localhost:8080/myProject/
List of all servlets:
- [...]
- default: /
- jsp: *.jspx
- helloServlet: /hello-servlet
- [...]
```

Comment: http://localhost:8080/demo_war_exploded/hello-servlet ;it doesn't change anything,only runs index.JSP page

Comment: @Jay So the `index.jsp` works, but the servlet doesn't? I just tested your code in a project of mine, works fine and dispalys `Hello World`.

Comment: I don't change anything, it's a generated code by project initialization.

Comment: I've changed the project from JAVA EE 8 to java Jakarta ee. it is working fine now. I think this is a  problem with a JAVA ee 8.